# How is it that if statements check types?

Tags: javascript

I come from a C# background and need to become more familiar with JS.  I'm reading a book and in this example:

```
var as = document.getElementsByTagName('a');
for(var i=0;i<as.length;i++){
    t=as[i].className;
    //Check if a link has a class and if the class is the right one
    if(t && t.toString().indexOf(popupClass) != -1)
    {
       //...
    }
```

Part of the `if` statement doesn't make sense.  What is `if(t)`?  I am used to if statements checking boolean values, but `t` is a string, right?

Comment: +1 to SO.  Many great answers.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The if statement does type coercion.

`if (o) block;`

will only run the block. if `o` is "truthy"

The following values are falsy:

`"", null, undefined, false, 0, NaN`

The rest are truthy.

A good article can be found [here](http://11heavens.com/falsy-and-truthy-in-javascript)

More to the point you have lots of dead code.

```
var as = document.getElementsByTagName('a');
for(var i=0;i<as.length;i++){
    t=as[i].className;
    // no need to check for whether t exists. No need to cast it to a string
    if(t.indexOf(popupClass) !== -1) // use !== for strict equality
    {
       //...
    }
```

Comment: I think i'm getting conflicting answers regarding if(t) from @DVK and this solution. What heppens if t is null or undefined and then try to evaluate indexOf()? In C# I would expect an object reference error.

Comment: @P.Brain.Mackey you can assert that `document.getElementsByTagName` returns a list of `HTMLElement` and you can assert that `HTMLElement` have a `className` attribute. You can then assert that the type is `string` and that `t` has an `indexOf` method. I know what the check is for but the check never fails.

Answer (score 2):

`if(t)` checks if `t` is **truthy**.

http://11heavens.com/falsy-and-truthy-in-javascript

In this specific case, the most likely purpose of the check was to eliminate the possibility that t is `null` or `undefined`.

Answer (score 2):

JavaScript performs automatic [*type conversion*](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Type_conversion). These values evaluate to boolean `false`:

- `null`
- `undefined`
- `0`
- `""`
- `false`
- `NaN`

Anything else evaluates to `true`.

So it tests whether `t` has some *truthy* value and then performs some operation on `t`. If this wasn't done (e.g. if `t` is `undefined` or `null`), `t.toString()` would throw an error.

Answer (score 1):

Have a look at the '[How good C# habits can encourage bad JavaScript habits](http://enterprisejquery.com/2010/10/how-good-c-habits-can-encourage-bad-javascript-habits-part-1/)' posts.

Basically, all these values are the same (false):

```
false
null
undefined
"" // empty string
0
NaN // not a number
```

So `if(t)` checks if the object is `false`, `null`, `undefined`, etc, etc...

Comment: There only the same in an if statement, `false == null` returns `false`

Comment: `NaN` is actually a number… a special one. Anyway, it's falsy.

Comment: @Nyuszika7H: But `NaN` is short for *not a number*.

Comment: @Felix Yep, I know. This is why I left that alone.

Answer (score 0):

if(t) is checking to see if t is a valid object. if(t) is like if(t != null).

Comment: So the if statement is not checking the literal value of t, rather whether the object has an address?

Answer (score 0):

> ### Type casting
>
> JavaScript is a *weakly typed* language, so it will apply *type coercion* wherever possible.
>
> ```
> // These are true
> new Number(10) == 10; // Number.toString() is converted
>                       // back to a number
>
> 10 == '10';           // Strings gets converted to Number
> 10 == '+10 ';         // More string madness
> 10 == '010';          // And more 
> isNaN(null) == false; // null converts to 0
>                       // which of course is not NaN
>
> // These are false
> 10 == 010;
> 10 == '-10'
> ```
>
> In order to avoid that the use of the [strict equal operator](http://bonsaiden.github.com/JavaScript-Garden/#equality) is recommended.
>
> But this does still not solve all the issues that arise from JavaScript's weak typing system.

Source: [JavaScript Garden](http://bonsaiden.github.com/JavaScript-Garden/#casting)

Comment: This seems a little off topic. The `if()` doesn't use the equals operators. It does a boolean evaluation of the value.

Comment: Be careful about confusing truthy/falsy values with the == operator.